# Migrating to Google Apps Hangouts - need to automatically add everyone in the domain

Tags: google-apps, google-hangouts

We are migrating away from a more primitive chat client to Google Hangouts for Business -

The only trouble is - that there are no contacts in the hangouts list, by default - and while it is fairly straightforward to add someone from our domain, it would be a huge pain to tell everyone to manually add everyone else in the domain (especially since that would require a hell of a lot of clicking, etc)

Reviewing the Hangouts API - everything there seems to pertain only to a specific hangout - (and namely group video hangouts, at that)

So, the next best thing would perhaps be to go the route of using the Google+ API and using the API to add everyone to everyone else's circles -

But, there are two problems with that, which I am open to any suggestions on solving: 
1). Not all the users have G+ accounts set up on their company/domain account 
2). Future users would be left out of this, unless the script were run repeatedly - which, is honestly acceptable...

But, I'm hoping some one can tell me how to make it a default - where everyone has everyone else added to their hangouts contact list, automatically....

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!